# keepScreenOn and merged layout

Tags: android, layout, merge, include

I am using merged layout and keepScreenOn does not seems to work. Can you advice?
Sample code:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <include layout="@layout/abc"/>
    <include layout="@layout/def"/>
</merge>
```

Thank you, Ladislav.

Answer (score 0):

***In merge there is no attribute available named as keepScreenOn.*** android:keepScreenOn="true" is available for Layouts.

*The `<merge>` tag was created for the purpose of optimizing Android layouts by reducing the number of levels in view trees.*

*`keepScreenOn` attribute Controls whether the view's window should keep the screen on while visible.*

Comment: OK, but how do I than make my screen to be on using layout with merge?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The keepScreenOn should be set in java code, onCreate method instead of the xml.

Ladislav.